# Big Commerce Warranty info being displayed in Product description

Tags: tabs, bigcommerce

I have just reskinned a site for a client and trying to tidy up the product page, One item i want to change is how The warranty information is being displayed under the product description tab,and to have a seperate tab for it

I have checked the  product.html

```
        <div class="Content left_col" id="LayoutColumn2">
        %%Panel.ProductDetails%%

        <div class="product-description">
            %%Panel.ProductTabs%%
            %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
            %%Panel.ProductVideos%%
            %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
            %%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%
            %%Panel.SimilarProductsByTag%%
            %%Panel.ProductByCategory%%
            %%Panel.ProductVendorsOtherProducts%%
            %%Panel.ProductReviews%%
       </div>

        <div class="box-up-sell">
            %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%
         </div> 
    </div>
```

and check panels.productdescription

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel ProductDescription" id="ProductDescription">
<h3>%%LNG_ProductDescription%%</h3>
<div class="ProductDescriptionContainer">
    %%GLOBAL_ProductDescriptionOptimizerScriptTag%%
        %%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%
    %%GLOBAL_ProductDescriptionOptimizerNoScriptTag%%
</div>
<hr style="%%GLOBAL_HideSectionSeparator%%" class="ProductSectionSeparator" />
```

but cannot see where the warranty info is being pulled from

i thought it should have been in a seperate tab, any ideas where the warranty info is being pulled from and why is it not in its own tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be coming from the Product Warranty Panel (%%Panel.ProductWarranty%%). Your template code will determine the actual layout, but the injection of it should come from that panel assuming your product data is properly configured.